# Error while using linked server in job. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication

Tags: sql-server, jobs, azure-sql-managed-instance

In SQL managed instance, I have a job. In job procedure, it is using linked server which is also a SQL managed instance. With test login I can read the data using Linked server. I have created the job @owner_login_name with test. It is failing with error.

> Executed as user: xxx. Login failed.
> The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with
>  Integrated authentication.
> [SQLSTATE 28000] (Error 18452).  The step failed.

Should I create trust group
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/server-trust-group-overview?view=azuresql

And also how to connect to on-premises SQL Server with linked server and I also I have to use them in jobs.

Edit:

The other server will give me access only through windows authentication. How to create windows authentication login in my managed instance and create a linked server it uses windows authentication on other server which is on premise.

Comment: You cans use a SQL login instead of a windows login to do so. If the distant job has to use a system command, you will need also a proxy for the job.

Comment: Yeah thanks. Worked with sql authentication. Used Be made Using this securty context, gave remote user name and password.